# ConTeXt: Replace GraphicsMagick with ImageMagick for TIFF conversion

Tags: graphics, context

## Background

A number of figures (illustrations and graphs) are saved as CMYK TIFF files. ConTeXt automatically converts TIFF files to PDF files prior to embedding them in the PDF document it produces. This task is performed using GraphicsMagick. GraphicsMagick has a bug in it that will corrupt some TIFF files.

## Problem

The illustrations are embedded into the document in a couple of different ways:

- `\inline*externalfigure[../path/to/file]`
- `\externalfigure[../\BookIllustrationNumber/illustration]`

Where `\BookIllustrationNumber` is a macro that zero-pads the current section number. The mailing list shows one way to intercede conversion using ImageMagick: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/096583.html

```
\startluacode
figures.converters["jpg"]["lowres.jpg"] =
function( oldname, newname, resolution)
  os.execute(
    string.format(
      'convert -density %ix%i "%s" "%s"',
      resolution, resolution, oldname, newname
    )
  )
end

\stopluacode

\starttext
  \externalfigure
    [cat.jpg]
    [conversion=lowres.jpg,resolution=50,width=5cm]
\stoptext
```

This works, but requires modifying the existing external figures TeX code (`\inline` and `\externalfigure`) to invoke the customization.

## Question

How can ConTeXt be instructed to use ImageMagick instead of GraphicsMagick for TIFF files without changing the `\externalfigure` macro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override the `pdf` and the `default` converter for `tif` images with your own.  (It might actually be sufficient to override the `pdf` converter, but just to be sure I override the `default` one as well)

The default ConTeXt cow is a b/w image and perfectly suited for this test.  I generated a tiff version with GIMP.  You can also download it from here: https://transfer.sh/IRl93/cow.tiff (expires in 14 days).

You can also set a default resolution in the converter by checking the argument for emptiness.

```
\startluacode
local function converter(oldname, newname, resolution)
    if not resolution or resolution == "" then
        resolution = 50
    end
    os.execute(string.format(
        'convert -density %ix%i "%s" "%s"',
        resolution, resolution, oldname, newname)
    )
end
figures.converters.tif.pdf = converter
figures.converters.tif.default = converter
\stopluacode

\starttext
  \externalfigure[cow.tiff]
\stoptext
```